# Force symbolic x coords

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

My x-axis value disappears if the bar graph is not complete:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar = 5pt,
    bar width=12pt,
    x=1.75cm,
    ymin = 1,
    %ymax = 1000,
    ymode = log,
    axis on top,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    symbolic x coords={100, 250, 500, 1000},
    %restrict y to domain*=0:1200, % Cut values off at 14
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
        \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=1pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
    },
    nodes near coords={%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[sci, sci superscript, precision=2]{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
    },
    axis lines*=left,
    clip=false,
    ylabel={runtime [ms]},
    xlabel={image size [edge]},
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.22)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ]    
    \addplot coordinates {(100, 340) (250, 5716) (500, 50669)};
    \addplot coordinates {(100, 21.25) (250, 331.97) (500, 2722) (1000,21877)};
    \addplot coordinates {(100, 15.77) (250, 158.15) (500, 1287) (1000,13224)};

    \legend{Conventional, Separated, Separated with SIMD}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I just can't see the value 1000 on the x-axis because there are only 3 values for one group

Comment: Instead of `xtick=data,` use `xtick={100, 250, 500, 1000},`.

Answer (score 2):

One minimal effort fix is to use `xtick={100, 250, 500, 1000}` instead of `xtick=data`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar = 5pt,
    bar width=12pt,
    x=1.75cm,
    ymin = 1,
    %ymax = 1000,
    ymode = log,
    axis on top,
    %xtick=data,
    xtick={100, 250, 500, 1000},
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    symbolic x coords={100, 250, 500, 1000},
    %restrict y to domain*=0:1200, % Cut values off at 14
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
        \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=1pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
    },
    nodes near coords={%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[sci, sci superscript, precision=2]{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
    },
    axis lines*=left,
    clip=false,
    ylabel={runtime [ms]},
    xlabel={image size [edge]},
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.22)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ]    
    \addplot coordinates {(100, 340) (250, 5716) (500, 50669)};
    \addplot coordinates {(100, 21.25) (250, 331.97) (500, 2722) (1000,21877)};
    \addplot coordinates {(100, 15.77) (250, 158.15) (500, 1287) (1000,13224)};

    \legend{Conventional, Separated, Separated with SIMD}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the 1000 is not shown is, that `xtick=data` (only) plots the `xtick`s of the **first** `\addplot` command, which doesn't contain a corresponding coordinate.

To overcome this issue I present three options as solutions, from which option 1 is already presented in [Marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449364/95441) (but unfortunately without any explanation **where** OPs issue is coming from).

Nonetheless in this case this should be the simplest solution, because a simple copy/paste replacement of `data` with the `symbolic x coords` values solves the issue. Option 2 adds a dummy `\addplot` containing all coordinates and option 3 suggests to reorder the `\addplot` commands thus that one containing all coordinates is stated first (and of course the legend entries have to be reordered as well then).

Please note that I have removed all unrelated code so one is not distracted. For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=1,
        ymode=log,
        % option 1:
        % just make `xtick' and `symbolic x coords' contain the same values
        xtick=data,
%        xtick={100, 250, 500, 1000},
        symbolic x coords={100, 250, 500, 1000},
        enlarge x limits=0.2,
    ]

        % option 2:
        % add a dummy "forget plot" plot that contains all symbolic coords
        % `forget plot' doesn't increase the `cycle list index' and does not
        % count for the legend entries
        \addplot [
            forget plot,
            draw=none,
        ] coordinates {(100,100) (250,100) (500,100) (1000,100)};

        \addplot coordinates {(100, 340) (250, 5716) (500, 50669)};
        % option 3:
        % make one of the plots that contains all the symbolic coords the first
        % `\addplot' command (and don't forget to adapt the legend entries
        % accordingly)
        \addplot coordinates {(100, 21.25) (250, 331.97) (500, 2722) (1000,21877)};
        \addplot coordinates {(100, 15.77) (250, 158.15) (500, 1287) (1000,13224)};

        \legend{
            Conventional,
            Separated,
            Separated with SIMD,
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]